# Mac OS - swift - CABasicAnimation current value

Tags: swift, macos, animation, appkit, caanimation

I have a CABasicAnimation moving a NSHostingView (it's a scrolling marquee text). When the user get his mouse cursor over the view, the animation must stops and it can interact with the view.

I tried the following approaches:

**Method 1:**
As recommended by Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW14), I tried to implement the pause/resume method using the convertTime / speed = 0.
It works, the animation is paused and resumed, but while the animation is paused, the coordinates of the user clic inside the view are the one of the model layer and not the one of the presentation layer. So the click respond to where the user would have click if their was no animation.

**Method 2:**
I tried the various animation flags on my `CABasicAnimation` as follow :

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position");
animation.duration = 10
animation.fromValue = [0, self.frame.origin.y]
animation.toValue = [-500, self.frame.origin.y]
animation.isCumulative = true
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = .forwards
```

Not matter what I use, when the animation is removed, the view get back to it's original position (it jumps back to it's original position).

**Method 3:**
I tried to save the current animation value before removing by reading the presentation layer position as follow:

```swift
print("before")
let currentPosition = layer.presentation()?.position
print("after")
```

But this method never returns! (ie. "after" is never printed). Could it be a bug or something?

I'm out of idea now. If anyone has a suggestion, it would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `layer?.presentation()?.position` doesn't work because `animation.fromValue` and `animation.toValue` should be `CGPoint` values:

```swift
animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y)
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: -500, y: self.frame.origin.y)
```

Then Method 3 works just fine.

Comment: It indeed fix the problem! Thank you very much. I still have an issue with click events, after the frame has moved. Any idea how I can refresh the tracking area? My NSHostingView contains Swift UI views with onTapGesture opening a popover, but when clicking inside the animated frame, the click responds like the view has never moved.

Comment: By updating the view.frame when the animation is paused, I've able to have the correct interaction area.